# How to convert stored procedures in UCCX to SQL queries?

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I am new to stored procedures(sp), Informix, and UCCX. there are several UCCX stored procedures that could be great time savers for bringing the UCCX report.
but I want to create these results using SQL queries or using python to use in my ETL.
I know the appropriate sp and its argument for my purpose, but I don't know how to convert this stored procedure to a SQL query or a Python instruction.

Can anyone offer a way to convert these sp's to SQL queries?

Comment: We can't see the SPL (stored procedure language) for the stored procedures — you have not shown it to us.  We've no idea how you might convert what we can't see into SQL queries.  There are things that can be done in SPL that cannot easily be replicated in plain SQL.  If the procedures are using some of those techniques, there may be nothing that can be done.

Comment: this link lists all of the stored procedures
https://community.cisco.com/t5/collaboration-knowledge-base/cuic-uccx-stored-procedure-list-pulled-from-v11-5/tac-p/4102662/highlight/true#M9701

and specifically, I wanna convert "sp_call_csq_agent"

Comment: Do you have the definition of the stored procedure available to you?  It may be visible in the sysprocbody system catalog table for the database — unless Cisco has removed the text from the table, leaving just the encoded p-code for the procedure.  Your link seems to list the stored procedures, but and there's information about the parameters (and `sp_call_csq_agent` seems to have a lot of parameters — 14 if I counted correctly).  We are still running blind!

Comment: I don't have the definition of sp, but the list of all needed arguments is shown in the link which I sent before. actually, these arguments are general and we can't understand anything from them.

Comment: To have any chance of replicating the stored procedure outside of the stored procedure, you will need the text of the stored procedure.  That is found in the `sysprocbody` table, using the data key `'T'`: `select p.owner, p.procname, p.procid, b.datakey, b.seqno, b.data from "informix".sysprocedures as p join "informix".sysprocbody as b on p.procid = b.procid where p.procname = 'sp_call_csq_agent' and b.datakey = 'T' order by p.owner, p.procname, p.seqno;` will identify the text of the procedure body, but it will probably be split over multiple sequence numbers.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If that produces no data, check that the procedure exists at all: `select p.owner, p.procname, p.procid from "informix".sysprocedures as p where p.procname = 'sp_call_csq_agent';`.  If that produces nothing, you'll need to look in a different database for the procedure.  If the procedure exists but no `'T'` records show up, then Cisco has hidden the procedure body from you — you won't be able to see what the procedure does at all easily.  With the segments of the procedure body, you'll be able to assemble the SPL source code and can analyze whether it can be written in SQL.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler
how you found sysprocbody? I didn't see any link or table to extract some detalis.

Comment: `"informix".sysprocbody` is a system catalog table present in every database in an Informix server — as is `"Informix".sysprocedures`.   That table must exist.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I ran your query and I saw an error message about p.seqno, but when I removed this item, I saw the result of the query.

Comment: The `p.seqno` in the `ORDER BY` clause should be `b.seqno`, of course.  My apologies — I goofed adding the ORDER BY clause after testing the rest of the query.